# Throwing error if element exists on insert of embedded doc

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to update a embedded document and throw an error if the element with the same parameter already exists with as few queries as possible.

i tried the following. :

```
public void AddUrlToList(Url url, Guid playListId)
{
    MongoCollection<PlayList> collection = GetPlayListForEdit();
    try
    {
        //DO better solution here... 
        var query = Query.EQ("UrlList.Url", url.UrlPart);
        var items = collection.Find(query).ToList();
        if (items.Count > 0)
            throw new Exception();

        //collection.Update(Query.And(Query<PlayList>.EQ(e => e.Id, playListId), Query.NE("UrlList", url.UrlPart)), Update.AddToSetWrapped("UrlList", url), WriteConcern.Acknowledged); 
        collection.Update(Query<PlayList>.EQ(e => e.Id, playListId), Update.AddToSetWrapped("UrlList", url));
    }
    catch (MongoCommandException ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Document:

```
 public class PlayList
    {
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Owner")]
        public Guid Owner { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("UrlList")]
        public List<Url> UrlList { get; set; }

        //Curret URL  info. 
        [BsonElement("CurrentUrl")]
        public string CurrentUrl { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("version")]
        public Guid version { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("time")]
        public string time { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("isRepeat")]
        public bool isRepeat { get; set; }
    }
public class Url
{
    [BsonElement("Url")]
    public string UrlPart { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

However i would rather want to do something in the style of the outcommented row where i assert with .NE or something that this element don't exist *and thow some kind of error/warning* .  Not sure how to acomplish  this without first specificaly trying to find this element and throw error if it exists. Mabey that is the only way to go ?

Anny suggestions are welcome, im kind of new to Mongo and the MongoC# driver.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know C#, but to me your code and your description don't match. You say you want to throw an error if "an element with the same parameter name" (as what?) already exists, but in the code your check is if some result set has > 0 results, as opposed to checking any result document for a certain "element with the same parameter name". I'm thinking you only want to update a document if it doesn't have the field you are trying to set on the document? Here's an example of doing that, in mongo shell code since I don't know C# very well:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "flavor" : "vanilla" })
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 1 }) // no flavor
> db.test.update({ "_id" : 0, "flavor" : { "$exists" : false } }, 
                 { "$set" : { "flavor" : "chocolate" } })
// no documents update - flavor field existed in doc w/ _id 0
> db.test.update({ "_id" : 1, "flavor" : { "$exists" : false } }, 
                 { "$set" : { "flavor" : "chocolate" } })
// doc w/ _id 1 updated
> db.test.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : 0, "flavor" : "vanilla" }
{ "_id" : 0, "flavor" : "chocolate" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whynot using Ensure Index? I'm using mongoC, but maybe in c# is like this:

```
 collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder()
 .Ascending("UrlList.Url"), IndexOptions.SetUnique(true));
```